# What should be the strategy to read from many tables having millions rows each in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, partition

I have following scenario while using postgresql -
No of tables - 100 ,
No of rows per table - ~ 10 Million .
All the tables have same schema E.g. each table contains daily call records of a company. So 100 tables contain call records of 100 days.

I want to make following type of queries on these tables -
For each column of each table get count of records having null value in that column.

So considering above scenario, what can be the major optimizations in table structures ? How should i prepare my query and does there exist any efficient way of querying for such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Postgres table inheritance, a simple `select count(*) from calls where foo is null` will work fine. It will use an index on foo provided null foo rows aren't too common.

Internally, that will do what you'd do manually without table inheritance, i.e. `union all` the result for each individual child table.

If you need to run this repeatedly, maintain the count in memcached or in another table.

Comment: Thanks Denis for the useful reply. I have following question -
In the query "select count(*) from calls where foo is null" the table "calls" is the master table with no data at all?

Comment: If i want to show count of null for all columns in one query then my query should be like -
select count(*) from calls where foo is null UNION select count(*) from calls where foo1 is null UNION select count(*) from calls where foo2 is null .....

Comment: @user3192919: yes; on the master table with no actual rows in it. Re the second question: use `union all` to avoid the (expensive) sort/distinct step, since there's no possibility for overlap.